# Upload file from another site to my webhost in CPanel

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel

My webhost is CPanel.Instead of downloading a file and then uploading that file to my webhost, I want to upload file from another site directly to my web host.

Is it possible by using CPanel default features?

Comment: Probably not. What have you tried?

Comment: What you want is not possible with the default features of CPanel.

Comment: Do you know any feature for this purpose? Actually I can not download and upload a large file due to my Internet bandwidth limitations!

Comment: If you have shell access I would just use `wget` to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound That is a greate idea. But even shell access is prohibited in my service :(

Comment: You are out of luck then get a new service provided shell access is a required feature out of my hosts

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have SSH access to your account, the only option that's left is for you to write a short PHP script that downloads the file for you. Simply execute this script (by visiting it) to start the download.

Be aware of the execution time limits set by your host though, since large downloads may exceed this limit.

```
<?php
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
?>
```

If the file is too large, or you're not comfortable writing PHP code. You may contact your hosting provider and ask them if they can download the file to your home directory for you. This should be a trivial task for them.